# Track multiple remote branches

Tags: git, git-remote

So let's say there are three developers: Alice, Bob, and Cecil. They decide to use Git without a central repo. They all set up remotes to each other, so that:

- Alice has `remotes/bob/master`
- Alice has `remotes/cecil/master`
- Bob has `remotes/alice/master`
- Bob has `remotes/cecil/master`
- Cecil has `remotes/alice/master`
- Cecil has `remotes/bob/master`

And now, Alice wants her local master branch to track *both* remote master branches. Is that even possible in Git? If not, what workflow do you guys use to work around this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[How to track more than one remote with a given branch using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282486/how-to-track-more-than-one-remote-with-a-given-branch-using-git)

In short, "can't be done unless you write a custom script/program/alias".

I suggest that they either agree on a common central branch that holds the development tree, or that they send each other pull requests instead of asking each developer to track every other developer.

Comment: This doesn't work well in some models. For example, I frequently fork github projects and work locally. I'd like to have git status tell me where I am relative to both origin and upstream, so I know if my fork is behind upstream.

Comment: Yeah I wish my github master could track the upstream master and my local master could track my github master and they all updated automatically