# Can i define multiple upstream branches for a local branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-push, git-pull

I'm looking to have a branch in git that has 2 upstream branches, such that it pulls from both of them and pushes to one of them...

Here's the scenario:

```
MY_BRANCH --> ORIGINAL_BRANCH 
MY_BRANCH --> MY_BRANCH
```

So, my new branch, `MY_BRANCH`, pulls from both `ORIGINAL_BRANCH` and `MY_BRANCH` (at the `origin`), and pushes to `MY_BRANCH` (at the `origin`).

Is this possible in git?
I've added `ORIGINAL_BRANCH` as the upstream, so when I go `git pull` it pulls from it.  And when I do `git push` it pushes to `MY_BRANCH`, which is good.
But how do I get it to follow `MY_BRANCH` as well, and pull from it too?
(reason for this is other developers might add something to it and not the `ORIGINAL_BRANCH`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in "[How to track more than one remote with a given branch using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282486/how-to-track-more-than-one-remote-with-a-given-branch-using-git)", you cannot register more than one upstream branch for a given local branch.

So you need to define an alias which will call `git pull` twice (with, for the second call, the `MY_BRANCH` from origin)