# What is the difference between `git rebase master` and `git rebase --onto master`?

Tags: git

Like the title says, what is the difference between `git rebase master` and `git rebase --onto master`?

I ran both commands expecting to see the exact same results but got two wildly different commit histories afterwards.

Whats the big deal here? How are they different from each other?

Comment: Here is an example of `onto` doing something you could not do without it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522977/341994

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: I forgot a last—or first—point, which I'll insert first here.  The *usage* for `git rebase` is, greatly simplified:

```
git rebase [ --onto <newbase> ] [ <upstream> ]
```

The square brackets `[...]` indicate that each argument is *optional*.  The angle brackets `<...>` mean *you fill in something here*.  The `--onto newbase` option uses a flag; the *`newbase`* is given (by you, the user) if and only if it's preceded by the keyword `--onto`, spelled with a double hyphen.  Similarly, the *`upstream`* argument is give if and only if you give it.  So:

```
git rebase master
```

gives one argument, an *`upstream`*, of `master`; `git rebase --onto master` gives one argument, a *`newbase`*, of *master*.  If you don't give an *`upstream`* argument, `git rebase` finds one on its own.  If you don't give a *`newbase`* argument, `git rebase` finds one on its own.  If you give one, but not the other, `git rebase` *still* finds the other one on its own.

As a one-liner answer, then: **`git rebase master` chooses `master` as *both target and upstream*, but `git rebase --onto master` chooses `master` as target, with the *default* upstream**, whatever that is for the current branch.  You can see the default for the current branch with:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{upstream}
```

If the current branch is, say, `dev`, and its upstream is `origin/dev`, then `git rebase master` means `git rebase --onto master master`, but `git rebase --onto master` means `git rebase --onto master origin/dev`.

#### What the various arguments mean

To perform its duties—which is to say, copy some commits, then move one branch name—`git rebase` needs to know three things:

- What commits should I copy?
- Where should I put these copies?
- What branch name should I move, in the end, after making copies?

The last of these defaults to the *current branch*.<sup>1</sup>  So you just run `git checkout` or `git switch` first, to select the correct branch.<sup>2</sup>

The Git authors cleverly crammed the remaining two of these three things into one argument to `git rebase`, which [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) calls the *`upstream`* argument.

Sometimes, however, you really need these two things to be *separate*.  The `--onto` flag allows you to separate them:

```
git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream>
```

copies the commits *to* the supplied *`newbase`*, rather than copying them *to* the supplied *`upstream`*.

The curious thing is not so much the *`newbase`*, which is pretty straightforward, but rather *how the *`upstream`* argument is used*.  The way it is used is complex, but to simplify it to essentials, Git runs:

```
git rev-list upstream..HEAD
```

(after doing the initial `git checkout` or `git switch`, if you provide a *`branch`* argument).  So *`upstream`* specifies not *what to copy*, but rather *what **not** to copy*.

**The rebase command *is* going to copy some set of commits.**  This is a given, because the goal of `git rebase` is to take some existing commits that are not *quite* good enough, in some way or form, and turn them into *improved* commits—but it is literally impossible to *change* any commit, once it is made.  Since the existing commits *can't* be changed, the best that `git rebase` can do is to *copy* them to new-and-improved *copies*, and then start using the copies in place of the originals.

The "use the copies instead of the originals" step is what makes it necessary to *move* one branch name.  Git *finds* commits using branch names.  Branch names move all the time, usually in a simple, one-step-at-a-time, easily followed manner.  But because names *can* move, `git reset` and other Git commands can move them, perhaps even violently, many commits at a time, abducting them from their home village in China and dropping them into the Australian Outback or whatever.   In the case of `git rebase`, the rebase code first copies the selected, old-and-lousy commits to their new home, making changes that—we hope—improve them, or at least make them fit into their new home.  Then it moves the branch name so that we find the *copies* instead of the originals—and then rebase is done.

The *`upstream`* argument specifies what *not to copy*, and sometimes—actually, remarkably often!—this *same* specifier *can be used* as the place that the to-be-copied commits should go.  But when it *can't* be used that way, the `--onto` argument lets you specify both *where to copy* and *what not to copy*, as two separate things.

[git | move old commit to the past of another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68522631/1256452) shows a case where it's convenient to specify *what not to copy* and *where to copy to* as two separate things.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, `git rebase` can *only* move the current branch (as of the latest Git versions, 2.32-ish, but probably for quite a while yet to come too)—so if you supply a branch name, `git rebase` *starts* by *using* `git checkout` or `git switch`.  See footnote 2.

<sup>2</sup>You can supply a branch name to the command line command.  If you do, the command currently literally runs or has built into it the necessary checkout/switch operation.  When the rebase is complete, you're on the branch you selected, even if you weren't before the rebase started.  That is, in:

```
git checkout main          # puts us on `main`
git rebase origin/foo foo
```

we might as well have run:

```
git checkout foo
git rebase origin/foo
```

anyway, because we end up on `foo`, not `main`.  But this does mean that if we *would* have to run `git checkout` foo, we can run:

```
git rebase origin/foo foo
```

or:

```
git rebase --onto target origin/foo foo
```

so as to get `git rebase` to do the `git checkout` for us.

Comment: But this is not what was asked. The question that needs answering, it seems to me, is the OP's claim that "I ran both commands [the specific commands `git rebase master` and `git rebase --onto master`] expecting to see the exact same results but got two wildly different commit histories afterwards." Either one must produce an example showing why that happened, or one must demonstrate that the OP is mistaken and it can't happen, they are identical if given under identical circumstances.

Comment: @matt: that's what the bit at the front (the edit) is about. `rebase --onto master` chooses `master` as the *target*, with the *default upstream;* `rebase master` chooses `master` as both the target *and* the upstream. (Maybe I should add that sentence.)

Comment: Really? So you're saying that "upstream" as a parameter name for rebase and "upstream" as the tracked remote-tracking branch are the same? Because I don't think so. This is the ambiguity discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262995/meaning-of-upstream-branch-in-rebase

Comment: The `upstream` argument to `git rebase` is whatever you like, but *if you don't supply one*, Git uses `@{u}`. (Where rebase is strange, as it were, is that if you don't supply an `--onto`, the default `--onto` is the `upstream` you supplied or defaulted. If you defaulted it, this makes sense, but if you supplied an upstream argument, this can be a surprise.)

Comment: That, if true, is the whole key to the mystery. That, and the missing third parameter. This is why I like `onto` with three parameters; it's the only one where I'm pretty sure I know what's going to happen. Thus for example where you say "If the current branch is, say, `dev`, ... then `git rebase master` means `git rebase --onto master master`" I would have said it means `git rebase --onto master master dev`.

Comment: @matt: It's why I like rebase with explicit `--onto` and upstream. I dislike supplying the third (argument-to-checkout/switch) parameter because I think rebase should just *always* use the *current* branch, forcing the *user* to use `git checkout` or `git switch` first. (That's because `git merge` always uses the current branch, so that makes the commands slightly more symmetric.)

Answer (score 14):

*[Do not accept this answer. It's just a sort of commentary on torek's answer.]*

The way to look at this, in my opinion, is to understand that the full form of `git rebase` is with `onto` and three parameters:

```
git rebase --onto x y z
```

To read that, in your mind clump `y` and `z` together, and swap `--onto x` to the end (because that's the natural English order for direct object and prepositional phrase), so that the whole thing parses something like this (pseudo-code):

```
rebase (y z] onto x
```

In that pseudo-code, the expression `(y z]` means "starting right after `y` and continuing all the way to `z`." Git calculates what "starting right after `y`" means by working backwards from `z`, not forward from `y`, but the effect is generally the same.

So `git rebase --onto x y z` means: "Grab all the commits starting right after `y` and continuing all the way to `z`, and append them to `x`."

---

Very well. That's the *full* form of `git rebase`. When you omit any of the parameters, Git fills them in for you. And the way it does that is surprising. That's the reason for the results you're seeing.

So let's take a real example. Here's our starting position:

```
* f8696e6 (HEAD -> dev) z
* 103333e (origin/dev) y
* 559ad1f x
| * 8032a5d (origin/main, main) c
| * 2caa1e9 b
|/  
* 06c7439 a
```

Look carefully at the graph. We are on `dev`. We have a remote `origin`, and we are one ahead of our remote-tracking branch `origin/dev`. `dev` split off from `main` at `a`, and after that it goes

```
x y z
```

Meanwhile, `main` goes

```
a b c
```

Now let's try

```
git rebase main
```

We are on `dev`, so that means

```
git rebase main main dev
```

Which means "grab the commits start from after `main` and continuing  to `dev` — namely, `x` `y` `z` — and attach them to `main`." Here we go... Here's what we get:

```
* f6b903e (HEAD -> dev) z
* 4adb109 y
* e9cc7fd x
* 8032a5d (origin/main, main) c
* 2caa1e9 b
* 06c7439 a
```

Yup, just as I said. This, I think, is what most people expect when they use a one-parameter `git rebase`.

Okay, now start over. This time we'll say

```
git rebase --onto main
```

That, as torek's answer tells you, means

```
git rebase --onto main origin/dev dev
```

So that means "grab everything from `origin/dev` to `dev` — that's just `z` — and attach it to `main`. That's extremely surprising! We never said anything about `origin/dev`, but that's where Git is going to snip our branch as we rebase. Here we go... Here's what we get:

```
* 0dccc25 (HEAD -> dev) z
* 8032a5d (origin/main, main) c
* 2caa1e9 b
| * 103333e (origin/dev) y
| * 559ad1f x
|/  
* 06c7439 a
```

That's probably the kind of thing happened to you (the OP). And it's easy to see why you found it surprising!

So in my opinion the main takeaway is that if you leave out any of the three parameters, you may be surprised by what Git chooses for them. Therefore, also in my opinion, you should *not* leave out any of them! You just don't know what will happen if you do.

---

Final note: Okay, I lied a little. Remember the first result?

```
* f6b903e (HEAD -> dev) z
* 4adb109 y
* e9cc7fd x
* 8032a5d (origin/main, main) c
* 2caa1e9 b
* 06c7439 a
```

I left out `origin/dev` from that diagram. In reality, this what we now have:

```
* f6b903e (HEAD -> dev) z
* 4adb109 y
* e9cc7fd x
* 8032a5d (origin/main, main) c
* 2caa1e9 b
| * 103333e (origin/dev) y
| * 559ad1f x
|/  
* 06c7439 a
```

Notice the *duplication* of the `x` and `y` commits. That's what `git rebase` does: it copies commits. This is a tricky situation if we intend to push `dev`, because we will be asking the remote `origin` to forget about the `y` and `x` currently pointed to by `origin/dev`, and it isn't going to be happy about that.

Comment: Do note that when `z` is supplied, Git *begins* the process with a `git checkout z` or `git switch z` (depending on whether you like `checkout` or `switch` here), so that after it's all done, `git branch --show-current` shows that you're on `z`, even if you started on (say) branch `beagle`.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, maybe `(y, z]`, isn't that a thing in math? Set theory or something? Maybe I have it backwards.

Comment: @ikegami edited accordingly! Thx