# How do I use git rebase to move a commit?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

This is the state of my local repo.  I was at AAAAA and made commit CCCCC. I did a `git pull` and it pulled the commits and did an auto(ish) merge of BBBBB into CCCCC and made DDDDD. I don’t want that, so I killed DDDDD with a git reset.

> $ git tree --all

```
CCCCC (HEAD, main) foobar issue 666
| * BBBBB (tag: fubar, origin/main, origin/HEAD) fubar issue #69
|/  
* AAAAA foo
```

Instead of a merge, I want to move CCCCC onto BBBBB.  How do I rebase this?  Do I need to do a switch or checkout to BBBBB first?

```
* CCCCC (HEAD, main) foobar issue 666
* BBBBB (tag: fubar, origin/main, origin/HEAD) fubar issue #69
* AAAAA foo
```

Comment: Rebase is correct: `git fetch; git switch main; git rebase origin/main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebase is correct:

```
git fetch
git switch main
git rebase origin/main
```

You could probably just say `git pull --rebase` instead, but I'm not one to take chances.

Comment: I want to put my commit on top of origin/main.  Don’t I need to switch to that first?

Comment: Your commands worked, but I don’t understand why.  How did the rebase command know I wanted to move my commit there?  In mercurial you have to be on the commit you want to “rebase” too.  Hg doesn’t have a rebase command.

Comment: The syntax in Git is the other way around. The first parameter is what you want to rebase _onto_. And in the absence of other info, _what_ you want to rebase is "me". So my command means "rebase me (main) onto origin/main".

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit: Mercurial *does* have `hg rebase`, but you may have to enable it first. It's just a combination of graft + strip.

Comment: `The syntax in Git is the other way around.`

Wow, that really helps a lot.  I’ve been thinking the wrong way.  I still wish mercurial won the repo wars.  I find it a lot easier to use.

Comment: Oh, rebase will take a 2nd parameter?  So if I were on another commit I could `rebase BBBBB CCCCC` and it would have the same effect?

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit: `git rebase` is annoyingly complicated. See the documentation for full details. However, `git rebase origin/main main` literally means *first, run `git switch main`, then run `git rebase origin/main`*. If you started out on branch `dev` you end up on branch `main`. I personally despise this particular "feature" of `git rebase` as it surprises people a whole bunch: "wait what the ... why am I on `main` now?"

Comment: If you use a raw commit hash ID as the last argument to `git rebase`, the switch or checkout can take you into detached-HEAD mode. (I'm not sure if it does now, with the latest Git versions; it did before some of the recent rebase updates. But in fact there's a bug or two in the checkout/switch step of this kind of rebase at the moment, as well. I'm on the Git mailing list and someone is trying to fix some edge cases and discovered this.)

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit My best summary of the full three parameter syntax, which I actually prefer, is https://stackoverflow.com/a/68636306/341994

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you don't actually *move* a commit.  Instead, you copy it to a new and improved commit (with different hash ID).  This is true in Mercurial too.  However, the Mercurial interface for rebasing ("grafting") and history editing (`hg histedit`) tends to be a lot clearer to Mercurial newbies, than Git's rebase is to Git newbies.  (This is a general theme in Mercurial-vs-Git.)

In Git, commits are never actually tied to any particular branch.  Instead, Git *finds* commits by starting from some *branch name*—which is really much more like a Mercurial "bookmark"—and then working backwards.  The set of commits reached by this working-backwards part is said to be "on the branch".

As a result, when two or more branch names identify the *same* final commit—as if you had two or more bookmarks that point to the same commit in Mercurial—those commits are on the same branch, but as soon as you *move* one or both of those branch names in Git, those same two commits, totally unchanged, may not be on those same branches.

The `git rebase` command works by:

1. Saving the current branch name somewhere.
2. Enumerating the raw hash IDs of commits to be copied.
3. Using Git's *detached HEAD* mode to select some particular target (`--onto`) commit.  This is where the new copies will go.
4. Copying the commits, one at a time, as if by `git cherry-pick` (equivalent to Mercurial `hg graft` except that branch names don't matter: commits are never tied to any branch).
5. Last, yanking the branch name saved in step 1 to point to the last copied commit, and exiting "detached HEAD" mode to be back on the branch you were on in step 1.

To handle steps 2 and 3—the "which commits to copy" list, and the "target" commit—Git typically use a *single argument*.  That single argument is typically a target branch name.  The source of the commits-to-be-copied is thus the *current branch* (per step 1).  That's why we start with:

```
git switch main
```

or equivalent.

To list out the commits to be copied, Git then uses the rough equivalent of:

```
git log target..HEAD
```

which means *find commits reachable from `HEAD` but not from `target`*.  (Mercurial has this as well, using *`target::.`*, except that Mercurial's `::` graph operator includes both ends of the interval, while Git's is a half-open interval: it always excludes the leftmost commit.)

The detached-HEAD-checkout target is literally the *`target`* argument in this form.

In some cases, it's not possible to generate the correct list of commits this way, so `git rebase` has the `--onto` syntax, which is kind of weird:

```
git rebase --onto target upstream
```

The list of commits in step 2 is now `upstream..HEAD` instead of `target..HEAD`.  The checkout in step 3 is still *`target`*.

Given:

```
CCCCC (HEAD -> main) foobar issue 666
| * BBBBB (tag: fubar, origin/main, origin/HEAD) fubar issue #69
|/  
* AAAAA foo
```

the list of commit hash IDs that you'd like copied is just one element long, listing `CCCCC`.  The place you want the copies to go after is commit `BBBBB`.  So if needed—the `HEAD -> main` says it isn't—we `git checkout main` or `git switch main` to make commit `CCCCC` current (it's OK to do even if not needed, it's just a no-op then).  Then we run `git rebase origin/main`.

Git now lists all the hash IDs from here (`HEAD` or `CCCCC`) backwards: that's `CCCCC`, then `AAAAA`, then anything under there.  From this list, Git strips `BBBBB` (it's not there but that just makes the stripping-out go fast!), then `AAAAA`, then anything under there—leaving only `CCCCC`.

Now Git does a detached-HEAD checkout of `BBBBB`.  It then issues cherry-picks for all the commits in the saved list, in the right order.  There's just the one commit in that list: `CCCCC`.  So Git makes a new commit, `CCCCD` perhaps, that's like `CCCCC`, doing the same sort of thing, but that comes after `BBBBB`:

```
CCCCC (main) foobar issue 666
| * CCCCD (HEAD) foobar issue 666
| * BBBBB (tag: fubar, origin/main, origin/HEAD) fubar issue #69
|/  
* AAAAA foo
```

Now that all the copies are done, Git yanks the *name* `main` to here—to `CCCCD`—and re-attaches HEAD so that we have:

```
CCCCC foobar issue 666
| * CCCCD (HEAD -> main) foobar issue 666
| * BBBBB (tag: fubar, origin/main, origin/HEAD) fubar issue #69
|/  
* AAAAA foo
```

Commit `CCCCC` can't be *found*, though, so `git log` doesn't *show* it:

```
* CCCCD (HEAD -> main) foobar issue 666
* BBBBB (tag: fubar, origin/main, origin/HEAD) fubar issue #69
  
* AAAAA foo
```

and there's no longer any reason for the blank line either, so that goes away.