# How to rebase feature branch that was created from a feature branch that is no in master?

Tags: git

I had the following structure

```
A -> B -> G -> H  (master)
     |
     C -> D -> I  (F1)
          |
          E -> F  (F2)
```

Now F1 has been merged in to master and squashed, and I also pulled in so I have the following

```
A -> B -> G -> H -> CDI  (master)
     |
     C -> D -> E -> F    (F2)
```

Now what I want is

```
A -> B -> G -> H -> CDI      (master)
                     |
                     E -> F  (F2)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Say

```
git rebase --onto master F2~2 F2
```

This grabs the last two commits (`~2`) from the branch called F2 and copies them onto the tip commit of `master`.

Comment: For a full explanation of this syntax, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68636306/341994. Once you get this into your brain you will find yourself treating your history like DNA and `rebase` is CRISPR. :)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
git rebase --onto master D F2
```

or

```bash
git rebase --onto master F2~2 F2
```

You can learn about this from [this tutorial](https://womanonrails.com/git-rebase-onto) on `git rebase --onto`.

---

When doing tricky things like this, I like creating tag for the head of the branch I'm manipulating so I can easily undo errors.

For example,

```bash
git switch F2
git tag f2
git rebase --onto master D F2

# Check result here...

# Optionally undo what we did.
git switch F2
git reset --hard f2

# Clean up.
git tag -d f2
```

Comment: There is no need for the `checkout` lines before `rebase`, and I recommend saying `switch` instead in any case.

Comment: Yes, it's true. If you specify F2 as the third parameter with the `--onto` syntax, Git automatically switches to F2 before performing the rebase. Try it and see. That is exactly why there is no `switch` / `checkout` in my answer; it isn't needed.

Comment: @matt, I thought you were referring to the other `git checkout`. Adjusted as suggested.