# How can I make git-status check two different remotes?

Tags: git, git-status

Every git user is accustomed to this:

```
> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

However, recently I've started working with two remotes instead of one (heroku and github, pretty standard situation, I think), and it started to annoy me to only see 1 origin in `git status` output.

How can I add other remote so I would see something like this?

```
> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Your branch is up-to-date with 'heroku/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

*(This question has nothing to do with heroku or github, it's just a convenient example.)*

Comment: You get that output with `git status` because the local branch is set up to track the remote one. I'm not sure if you can set up a local branch to track more than one remote branch at a time. See the [`--track` option documentation for `git branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html).

Comment: Seems like this is currently not possible. Someone with some free time and knowledge of C should consider adding this functionality e.g. "git status -r other-remote" and sending a patch.

Comment: Similar question (and similar answer: not possible) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282486/how-to-track-more-than-one-remote-with-a-given-branch-using-git with a couple more linked there

Answer (score 13):

`git status` only shows the relative status to the remote **tracking** branch. But it's easy to change the remote tracking branch temporarily:

```
git branch -u <remote>/<branch>
```

Then `git status` will show the status of that branch.

Note that the changes displayed are the same, but the number of commits ahead/behind for the current remote tracking branch are properly displayed.

A bash script to get all remote branch status:

```
for o in $(git remote -v | grep fetch | cut -f 1 -); do # remote branch names
  git branch -u $o/master  # set remote tracking branch (git v1.8+ syntax)
  git status
  echo --------------------------------   # separator
  git branch -u origin/master >/dev/null  # restore original tracking branch
done
```

To get the status of both of your origins using the single command `git s`:

```
git config --global alias.s "for o in $(git remote -v | grep fetch | cut -f 1 -); do git branch -u $o/master; git status; echo; git branch -u origin/master >/dev/null; done"
```

This adds an alias to your ~/.gitconfig file (which you can later edit to change either the main remote branch or the command `s`).

Note that *origin/master* is hard-coded as the default branch. To work with any branch, without hard-coding, the script above could be modified to get the current remote+branch first, then restore it.

Comment: Well, that command just prints out the same as `git status`, only two times

Comment: It would be nice if it did give you "the status for both remotes (specified separately)", but it doesn't. See the docs at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html

Comment: @BenCreasy Good point. Since `git status` only works against the current remote tracking branch, I changed the example to change the tracking branch before asking for the status.

Comment: "... *the* remote tracking branch" -- but there can be as many remote tracking branches as remotes, hmm? `branch -a` does list *both* or my "remotes/<remotename>/master" branches just fine.

Answer (score 12):

`git status` is the status of your worktree, one-branch-at-a-time status.

if you want to see all-branch status, do

```
git branch -avvv
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, as of Git 2.28 at least, is "no".  As [Brent Faust wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458073/1256452), you must set the upstream of the current branch, then run `git status`, then set it again and run it again, if you want `git status` to print this information for multiple upstream values.

#### All is not lost

While you can't get `git status` to do this, you *can* use a different shell command to do what you want:

```
counts=$(git rev-list --count --left-right $chosen_upstream...$branch)
# note: three dots
```

The `counts` variable now contains two values: the "remote ahead, me behind" value, and the "remote behind, me ahead" value.  If both values are zero, your branch and the chosen upstream are even.  (If you want the counts swapped, swap the `$chosen_upstream` and `$branch` variables.)

To turn this into a more-useful shell function (valid in plain old `sh` and `bash` both):

```sh
# report: invoke as report upstream [branch]
report() {
    local branch upstream count
    case $# in
    1) branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null) || return 1;;
    2) branch="$2";;
    *) echo "usage: report <upstream> [<branch>]" 1>&2; return 1;;
    esac
    upstream="$1"
    count=$(git rev-list --count --left-right "$upstream...$branch") || return 1
    set -- $count
    case $1,$2 in
    0,0) echo "Your branch is up-to-date with $upstream";;
    0,*) echo "Your branch is $2 commits ahead of $upstream";;
    *,0) echo "Your branch is $1 commits behind $upstream";;
    *)   echo "Your branch and $upstream have diverged,"
         echo "and have $2 and $1 different commits each, respectively.";;
    esac
}
```

(The output from the above is designed to match that from `git status`, and isn't really appropriate for the two-argument form, but it shows how to do what you might want to do here.)

---

(answered in 2020 due to link from [How do I do git status upstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63606152/1256452))