# Passing upstream on git status

Tags: git

I have a working copy with two remotes, *origin* (which is my repo) and *fork*, which is where the project comes from. To check for updates I do this:

```
git branch master --set-upstream-to origin/master
git status
git branch master --set-upstream-to fork/master
git status
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'd take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455842/how-can-i-make-git-status-check-two-different-remotes  It doesn't seem you can quite do what you want, but an alias would at least keep you from having to do so much typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily *better*, but if you are just looking for revision counts:

- The number of commits you are "ahead of" a remote-tracking branch is the number of commits that are reachable from your branch, but not from that remote-tracking branch:

  ```
  git rev-list --count origin/master..master
  ```

  and

  ```
  git rev-list --count fork/master..master
  ```

  respectively.
- The number of commits you are "behind" a remote-tracking branch is the symmetric opposite: the number of commits that are reachable from the remote-tracking branch, but not from your own branch:

  ```
  git rev-list --count master..origin/master
  git rev-list --count master..fork/master
  ```

These are the various counts that `git status` (or `git branch -v`) show.  Having `origin/master` as the current upstream for `master` means that `git status` will count `master..origin/master` and `origin/master..master`.

Pictorially, this might look something like this, where each uppercase letter stands for one of those big ugly commit hash IDs:

```
          F--G         <-- origin/master
         /
...--B--C--D--E        <-- master
            \
             H--I--J   <-- fork/master
```

The count of commits on `master` that are not on `fork/master` is 1: that's commit `E`.  Commit `D` is on *both* `origin/master` and `fork/master`, and so are `C` and earlier, so there is just the one commit.  Meanwhile the count of commits on `fork/master` that are not on `master` is 3: those are commits `J`, `I`, and `H` (as with all things Git we work backwards, from newer to older).  `H`'s parent commit `D` is reachable from `master` by working backwards, so we stop counting there.

Similarly, the count for `origin/master..master` is 2 (`E` and `D`), and the count for `master..origin/master` is also 2 (but these are `G` and `F` this time).

You can even get a count for `origin/master..fork/master`—it's 4: `J`, `I`, `H`, and `D`—and for `fork/master..origin/master` (it's 2: exercise: which 2?).  (You cannot get this from `git status` because you cannot set an upstream for a remote-tracking branch.  You must run `git rev-list` directly.)

#### A shortcut (advanced study item)

To avoid having to run `git rev-list --count` twice, you can get *both* counts at once.  Using a symmetric difference selector (see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)) such as `origin/master...master`—note the *three* dots instead of two—we can select all commits that are reachable from *either* tip commit, but not from *both* tip commits.  Adding `--left-right` makes `git rev-list` keep track of *which* tip resulted in selecting the commit, and adding `--count` then prints *both* counts, separately.  So:

```
git rev-list --left-right --count origin/master...master
```

tells us how many we're "behind" (left side) and "ahead" (right side), in one command.  (Swap the two names and you get "ahead" first, then "behind".)

Comment: Very succinctly put-together answer, a good explanation!